# Asp.Net Web Api2 + SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

Help me please!

I have some project of Mail. I need to use SignalR. 
Now I only have this in my Startup

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

I Have Hub

```
[HubName("MailHub")]
public class MailHub<THub>: Hub
    where THub : IHub
{
    public void SendMessage (Mail message)
    {
        Clients.Caller.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

I Have MailController

```
 [Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/mail")]
public class MailController : ApiController

{

    private readonly MailStore<Mail> _mail;

    public MailController()
    {
        _mail = new MailStore<Mail>(MongoUtil<Mail>.GetDefaultConnectionString());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("send")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendMessage(Mail message)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MailHub<IHub>>();

        if (hubContext != null)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;

            var sendMessage = new Mail
            {
                Subject = message.Subject,
                Sender = message.Sender,
                Receiver = message.Receiver,
                Message = message.Message
            };

            await _mail.CreateAsync(sendMessage);

          //  hubContext.Clients.Clien....;

            /*   if (!result.Succeeded)
               {
                   return BadRequest(ModelState);
               }
               */
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

And How I Can use SignalR at this Controller?
I need that some user send e-mail to another user using SignalR.

Comment: Where is your jquary code?

Comment: My work is to make backend. Jquary code will make another dev.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you can send an email in the same way as you are doing in the controller.

```
[HubName("MailHub")]
public class MailHub<THub>: Hub
    where THub : IHub
{
    public void SendMessage (Mail message)
    {
        var sendMessage = new Mail
        {
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Sender = message.Sender,
            Receiver = message.Receiver,
            Message = message.Message
        };
        await _mail.CreateAsync(sendMessage);
    }
}
```

or more simply:

```
[HubName("MailHub")]
public class MailHub<THub>: Hub
    where THub : IHub
{
    public void SendMessage (Mail message)
    {
        await _mail.CreateAsync(message);
    }
}
```

There's no inherent requirement for SignalR to send a response back to the SignalR client (unless you wanted to), just receive the parameters and send the mail as you would in the controller.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a lot of methods like SendMessage, ShowAllMessages, and other. How I can get acces to them in MailHub? I need some route to every method. And one more thing: I need that SignalR send notofication to receiver! How I can do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I change the method to be static and then I was able to call in MVC controler with classname.methodname . I think you can do the same .please try and let me know.

```
      [HubName("MailHub")]
    public class MailHub<THub>: Hub
          where THub : IHub
    {
    // change to static
    public static void SendMessage (Mail message)
    {
       IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MailHub>();
       context.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
     }
}
```

Comment: It is error - Cannot acces non-static property "Clients" at static context

Comment: @OlegLyahovetskyi please try now :)

Comment: Not error. But i don't understand. Look at please. In the Controller i have code that send message, after this I need to call MailHub - MailHub<IHub>.SendMessage(sendMessage) ? Like this? And I need that SignalR send notofication to receiver! How I can do this? Thank you

Comment: In thr controller use like this MailHub.SendMessage("testmessage") ; I am using it in my application MVC and it work fine . May be your  some issues in your javascript code .

Comment: @OlegLyahovetskyi where are you jquery files which you needfor signalr notification and update ?